AWS Cloudwatch Dashboards - Widget Arrangement
I am having difficulty placing the Dashboard Widgets within Cloudwatch Dashboards.
I'm convinced that maybe deploying AWS Dashboards through the CDK was not as carefully coded out by AWS as might be desired. I'm pretty sure I've coded it out correctly, and I'm hoping to get a second set of eyes.
The "TL;DR" version of this is, is that I can't place a widget on the cartesian coordinates "Y:6, X:0". That is to say, in the first slot on the second row. My hunch is that it has something to do with the "Lambda Errors" widget.
As I was placing that one originally, there were only two widets. The "All Calls" and the "Lambda Errors". For some reason, whenever I tried to deploy the Lambda Errors widget where it was, it would always fall to the right of "All Calls". So I had the idea of placing the "Missed Calls" widget next, and then placing the "Lambda Errors" below. However, when I did that it just kept moving to the right.
I wound up settling on the expedient of writing the next set of widgets, and then seeing if I could just "slide" the lambda errors widget in by default. That worked, but when I tried to place the "Lambda Errors - Overall" graph on the next line, it always deploys to the left.
What Have You Tried To Fix This:

I have double checked to confirm which coordinate is "X" and which is "Y" in the widget placement. I have satisfied myself that I am placing them correctly by experimenting with them to confirm.
I have tried to shrink the size of the last widget on the proceeding line, the "Concurrent Calls" widget to see if there was something about the size of the widget that might have been "bumping" the widget on the next line over. Even when I set it's size to 5 (from 6) it moves.
I have tried to shrink the "lambda errors widget" (the short and stocky one on the proceeding line and immediately above the problemed widget.


Below you will find the code body for the entire dashboard. I would direct your attention to the bottom section of the code to where the position method is invoked. The two widgets that I've discussed are called, lambdaErrorsWidgetGraph (The problemed widget) and the other lambda errors widget is called, lambdaErrorsWidget
export class CloudwatchConstruct extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string){
        super(scope, id, {
            env: {
                account: process.env.AWS_ACCOUNT,
                region: process.env.AWS_REGION
            }
        });
    
        const awsVariables = {
            Region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
            AmazonConnect: {
                ConnectInstanceId: String(process.env.AWS_CONNECT_INSTANCEID)}
        }

        const dashboard = new Dashboard(this, 'Dash', {
            dashboardName: 'AdvisoryDash'
        });

        //Row #1

        //    Widget #1: All Calls
        const callsPerIntervalMetric = new Metric({
            namespace: 'AWS/Connect',
            metricName: 'CallsPerInterval',
            dimensionsMap: {
                InstanceId: awsVariables.AmazonConnect.ConnectInstanceId,
                MetricGroup: 'VoiceCalls'
            },
            label: 'Calls',
            statistic: 'Sum',
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            region: awsVariables.Region
        });

        const singleWidget = new SingleValueWidget({
            metrics: [callsPerIntervalMetric],
            width: 3,
            height: 3,
            title: "All Calls",
            sparkline: false
        })

        //      Widget #2: Missed Calls:
        const missedCallsMetric = new Metric({
            namespace: 'AWS/Connect',
            metricName: 'MissedCalls',
            dimensionsMap: {
                InstanceId: awsVariables.AmazonConnect.ConnectInstanceId,
                MetricGroup: 'VoiceCalls'
            },
            statistic: 'Sum',
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            color: '#d62728',
            region: awsVariables.Region
        });

        const missedCallsWidget = new SingleValueWidget({
            metrics: [missedCallsMetric],
            width: 3,
            height: 3,
            title: "Missed Calls",
            sparkline: false
        });

        //      Widget #3:
        const throttledCallsMetric = new Metric({
            namespace: 'AWS/Connect',
            metricName: 'ThrottledCalls',
            dimensionsMap: {
                InstanceId: awsVariables.AmazonConnect.ConnectInstanceId
            },
            statistic: 'Average',
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            region: awsVariables.Region
        })

        const throttledGraphWidget = new GraphWidget({
            height: 6,
            width: 6,
            title: 'Throttled Calls',
            leftYAxis: {
                showUnits: false,
                min: 0,
                label: "Number Of Throttled Calls"
            },
            stacked: false,
            region: awsVariables.Region
        })
        //attaching metric to widget
        throttledGraphWidget.addLeftMetric(throttledCallsMetric)

        //      Widget #4: IMetric already instantiated. Re-using - See Widget #2.
        const missedCallsGraphWidget = new GraphWidget({
            height: 6,
            width: 6,
            title: "Missed Calls - Over time",
            leftYAxis: {
                showUnits: false,
                min: 0,
                label: "Calls"
            },
            rightYAxis: {
                label: "Time",
                showUnits: false
            }
        })
        
        missedCallsGraphWidget.addLeftMetric(missedCallsMetric)

        //      Widget #5: Concurrent Calls
        const concurrentCallsMetric = new Metric({
            namespace: 'AWS/Connect',
            metricName: 'ConcurrentCalls',
            dimensionsMap: {
                InstanceId: awsVariables.AmazonConnect.ConnectInstanceId
            },
            statistic: 'Sum',
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            region: awsVariables.Region
        })

        const concurrentCallsWidget = new GraphWidget({
            height: 5,
            width: 5,
            title: 'Concurrent Calls',
            leftYAxis: {
                label: "Calls",
                showUnits: false
            },
            rightYAxis: {
                label: "Time",
                showUnits: false
            }
        })

        concurrentCallsWidget.addLeftMetric(concurrentCallsMetric)

        // Widget #6
        const lambdaErrorMetric = new Metric({
            namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
            metricName: 'Errors',
            dimensionsMap: {
                InstanceId: awsVariables.AmazonConnect.ConnectInstanceId
            },
            statistic: 'Sum',
            region: awsVariables.Region,
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            color: '#d62728'
        })

        const lambdaErrorsWidget = new SingleValueWidget({
            metrics: [lambdaErrorMetric],
            width: 6,
            height: 3,
            title: 'Lambda Errors',
            sparkline: false
        })

        //      Widget #7:

        const lambdaErrorsWidgetGraph = new GraphWidget({
            height: 6,
            width: 6,
            title: 'Lambda Errors - Overall',
            leftYAxis: {
                label: "Errors",
                showUnits: false
            },
            rightYAxis: {
                label: "Time",
                showUnits: false
            },
            period: Duration.minutes(5),
            statistic: 'Sum',
            region: awsVariables.Region
        })
        
        lambdaErrorsWidgetGraph.addLeftMetric(lambdaErrorMetric)

        // Add widgets with their positions
        dashboard.addWidgets(singleWidget,missedCallsWidget,throttledGraphWidget,missedCallsGraphWidget, concurrentCallsWidget,lambdaErrorsWidget,lambdaErrorsWidgetGraph);
        //Row #1
        singleWidget.position(0,0); 
        missedCallsWidget.position(3,0)
        throttledGraphWidget.position(6,0)
        missedCallsGraphWidget.position(12,0)
        concurrentCallsWidget.position(18,0)
        //Be careful about the 'position' on this one. Not clear to me that the position function works as intended in certain cases.
        lambdaErrorsWidget.position(0,3)
        //Row #2
        lambdaErrorsWidgetGraph.position(0,6)
        
    } // Constructor
} // Class


Try exporting the JSON view of the dashboard and inspecting it. And then do the same after manually dragging the widget into the desired position.
